# ¿Como puedo mandar datos a un select desde mi base de datos con NODEJS y javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, express

Necesito mandar datos desde mi base de datos a un SELECT con JAVASCRIPT, estoy trabajando con NodeJs pero todavía soy principiante en esto de desarrollo web, agradezco su ayuda.

Codigo donde recibo los datos de mi base de datos:

```
cargarCPais:function(conexion){
    
    conexion.query("SELECT Codigo FROM aplicacion.pais",function(err,rows){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            darValor(rows);
        }
    });
    function darValor(value){
        var cPais = value;
        console.log(cPais);
    }
}
```

intento de recibir datos de la consulta y enviarlos al select

```
iPersonal:function(req,res){
    res.render('candidato/informacion_personal',{title:'Candidato : Informacion Personal'});
    candidato.cargarCPais(con);
    var paisSelect = req.body.document.getElementById('pais');// el select tiene como nombre pais
    paisSelect.addEventListener("change", descargarPais);
    let codigo = candidato.cargarCPais(con);
},
```

Comment: Que tal Delta, define  a que te refieres al mandarlos a un **select** a  un elemento de HTML  y este los muestre o a la consulta misma, no logro entender tu pregunta

Comment: lo que pasa que es una pagina de información personal , entonces estos select debe de tener cargados los datos que estan en una tabla en la base de datos, en mi caso el select debe de cargar los nombres de los paises que los tengo registrados en la base de datos

Comment: la tabla Pais tiene los campos Codigo , Pais , ejemplo: MXN , Mexico